# Does this reasoning work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Consider the following system of ODEs.

$$
\theta'=r\\
r'=1-r^2
$$

On the unit circle, $\theta'=1$, and $r'=0$

Now consider the system

$$
\theta'=1\\
r'=0
$$

The solution curves to this system are circles. Is this enough to conclude that the unit circle is a solution to the first system? Does this reasoning work in general?

In other words, given two systems $x'=f(x)$, and $x'=g(x)$, with $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and a curve $h(x)=0$. If $f(x)=g(x)$ on $h(x)=0$, and $h(x)=0$ is an invariant set under the flow of one dynamical system, is it necessarilly an invariant set of both?

Comment: Let me see if I understand:  Given a general system (1) $y'=F(t,y),$ we make a substitution $y=a(t)$ on the right hand side and get a new system  (2) $y'=F(t,a(t)).$     Do solutions of (2) necessarily generate solutions of (1)?   In general,  No.   The system you presented has an artifact where the vector field associated to both systems just happens to be tangent the unit circle (with the same speed!).

Comment: @mattbiesecker That's not quite what I meant. I'll edit my question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Thanks.  The answer is yes.  The answer below is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I may have misinterpreted the question.)

Given the systems $\dot{x}_k = f_k(x_k,t)$, suppose $y$ is a solution to the $f_1$ system and
$f_2(y(t),t) = f_1(y(t),t)$, then $y$ must be a solution to the $f_2$ system.